# How will a taser act when one neither or only the receiver is grounded?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields

Person $A$ has a taser and person $B$ is being tased. How will the current affect the two people when :

1. Neither $A$ nor $B$ is connected to the ground (earthed)
2. $A$ is earthed, $B$ is not

Additionally, I learnt quite sometime ago about and parallel connections. If two or more people are connected together (like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4BpoAKVn6k)), will the circuit be a series or a parallel one?

Comment: Isn't the ground relative to the circuits within a taser or do people really need to be touching an electrical ground?

Answer (score 0):

A [taser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taser) fires two darts into the target, which are connected to the device by thin insulated copper wires. The main path of the modulated current that passes through the target's body is from one dart to the other - there is no need for either the target or the firer to be earthed.